# Convert QFile to FILE*

Tags: c++, file, qt, qfile

Is there another way to convet QFile to File? Different than this:

```
QFile myFile("goforward.raw");
int FileDescriptor = myFile.handle();
FILE* fh = fdopen(FileDescriptor, "rb");
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Can't you simply use the `QFile` for file operations?

Comment: And what's not working with what you have there?

Comment: Because I use this function: png_init_io(png_ptr, fh); where the second param is File *.                                           Thanks                                                                And yes work with code there but I like to use the only library QFile.

Comment: This code is the way to do it.  So explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Qt also supports reading and writing PNG files directly from QFile, with QImage::load/save or QImageReader/QImageWriter (or just QPixmap if there is only one PNG image per file).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going try to use QImege or QPixmap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you already know that you have the various `open`, `read`, etc. methods in QFile. That said, if the file is not opened, then the `handle` method returns an error.

```
QFile myFile("goforward.raw");
myFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
int fileHandle = myFile.handle();
```

After that, you might reopen it with:

```
FILE* fh = fdopen(fileHandle, "rb");
```

Answer (score 13):

We had very strange problems with our application and finally traced it to the QFile/fdopen issue:

```
void foo(QString filename)
{
    QFile qf(filename);
    qf.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    int fd = qf.handle();
    FILE* f = fdopen(fd, "rb");
    // do some stuff with f
    fclose(f); // !!! undefined behaviour !!!
}
```

The problem with this code is that fclose(f) is called before the QFile object is destroyed, which is the wrong order: [QTBUG-20372](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-20372)

...so either destroy the QFile object before calling fclose() or duplicate the file descriptor returned by QFile::handle():

```
void foo(QString filename)
{
    QFile qf(filename);
    qf.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    int fd = qf.handle();
    FILE* f = fdopen(dup(fd), "rb"); // !!! use dup()
    // do some stuff with f
    fclose(f); // correct
}
```

P.S.: Those strange problems with our app showed up only on very few systems by a 10 second delay between a return statement at the end of a function and the actual return from that function. It was really weird. So this is an example of an "undefined behaviour" manifested in the real world :o)

Comment: What happens if you close `qf` before `f`? Can you continue using `f` after that?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the file name, why don't you simply use

```
QFile *file = fopen(filename.toLocal8Bit().data(), "rb");
```

?

Isn't it way simpler than creating the QFile, opening it, retrieving the handle, etc.?

And it is pretty bug-free...

Comment: This doesn't compile:
"error: cannot convert ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’ to ‘QFile*’ in initialization"