# Write/read int to QFile without using dataStream in C++

Tags: c++, qt, file, qfile

How can I write/read `qint32` variable to `QFile`? I need to do this without using `Data/TextStreams`. Just direct read/write.

```
QFile* file;
qint32 a, b;
//write a to file
//b = read a
```

Comment: Подойдет [link](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B2_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%A1%D0%B8)? And this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465727/convert-qfile-to-file)

Comment: Do you plan to make binary read/write? Maybe QDataStream is what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin not sure. I have QFile with its own read/write operations. I need to use "reinterpret_cast" here, which doesnt seem to be correct idea

Comment: @johngull i cannot use streams of any kind here, so not

Comment: @VoronkovIvan, strange limitation :) Maybe you can write all you need to QByteArray and then write it to the file?

Comment: You can use  QIODevice::read* and QIODevice::write* functions

Comment: @AlexanderChernin they dont give permission to read directly in int. Only idea is:  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a) );

Comment: Then you have no choice except making casting. Even inside QDataStream it is realized like `if(dev->read((char*)&i, 4)!=4) ...`